# How to query entities without no ancestors in appengine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Consider the following code snippet:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import pprint

class Entity(ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty()
     age = ndb.IntegerProperty()

entity = Entity()
entity.name = "hello"
entity.age = 23
entity.key = ndb.Key(Entity, "p1")
entity.put()

e2 = Entity()
e2.key = ndb.Key(Entity, "p2", parent=ndb.Key(Entity, "p1"))
e2.name = "he11o2"
e2.age = 34
e2.put()
```

I want to query the Entity table records that doesn't have any
parent associated with it. For the above example it should yield me only p1 entity.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can only query for things that exist in an index. Things with no value unless explicity set to None (and you can't do that for parents) can't be queried.

The only way I can suggest is have a computed property or some other property that you set to None if no parent or the parent key or a flag.  Then you can query for all entities with parent=None.  `parent` being a property of the entity.